# List already registered users in a login form drop down menu - ultimate member plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I created two user roles:

1. **Distributor**
2. **Sales agent**

I need to list all the registered users who are under "sales agent" user role only.

I need to list the users as a dropdown menu.(which is used in the registration form for distributors)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to filter the list by user role? How to create an HTML select input in WordPress? Something else?

Comment: i need to filter users by user role. and i need them listed in the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the trick?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'Your desired role goes here.',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );

echo '<select>';
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$user->ID.'">' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```